# Java jar to integrate with JMeter?

Tags: java, performance, automation, jmeter

As the JAR file is in /lib/ext folder that is having class and required packages. But i am making it run the error in console of JMeter

[image]

```
jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed! java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult.connectEnd()V
```